# Best way to fit google map view to contain a polygon in iOS Swift 2.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, google-maps, swift2

What is the best way to let google map view display the whole Polygon (or Path) in `**Swift 2.1**` ?

Comment: are you tried any library / SDK ? I you try any way please describe in brief.

Comment: I am using google map SDK in iOS without any external libraries

Comment: I found this and I think it is a good one:

`let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(path: myPath)`
`map.animateWithCameraUpdate(GMSCameraUpdate.fitBounds(bounds))`
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it will helpfull ..

```
let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(path: path)
self.mapView!.animateWithCameraUpdate(GMSCameraUpdate.fitBounds(bounds, withPadding: 15.0))
```

Comment: Thank you, 
Also it is the same solution I have, But I benefit from `withPadding` parameter. Thanks